# QuickBook SDK QBFC is not allow to access the file without opening it in quickbook

Tags: quickbooks, qbfc

QuickBook SDK QBFC is not allow to access the file without opening it in quickbook. Please can any body let me what needs to be configured to access file without opening.

Getting error.

A QuickBooks company data file is already open and it is different from the one requested or there are multiple company files open.

Answer (score 4):

When opening a company file, you specify either the path, or omit the path. Omitting the path, uses the current company open in Quickbooks (on that pc). Specifying a path, allows you to open a specific company, regardless of weather its already open or not.

Also worth noting, to specify your "mode", single or multi access/user.

Worth noting, when first connecting, you need to have the company open, as it needs to pop  a permission dialogue allowing you to "authorize" the sdk / app connection.